# gnuplot - Histogram bars in different colors with the values on top

Tags: gnuplot

I have this data file (`TotalDurationBarPlot.dat`):

```
Indexed list 934
Tree list 3692
Array list 12274
Linked list 48188
```

What I wish to achieve is a histogram chart with 4 bars: one for **Indexed list**, one for **Tree list**, one for **Array list**, one for **Linked list**. My requirements are:

1. Each bar has it's unique color,
2. On top of each bar, there is a number denoting the height of the bar. (For example, above the **Tree list**, there is **3692**.)
3. It would be nice to have a legend on a light gray background with a thin black legend border at the top right corner.

**My current attempt**

As of now, my data file looks like:

```
# ILL TL AL LL
934 3692 12274 48188
```

... and my gnuplot script looks like:

```
set title font "Monospaced,13" 'Total duration'
set grid
set key right top
set style data histograms
set style histogram cluster gap 2
set style fill solid border 2
set xtics format ""
set grid ytics
set ylabel "Milliseconds"
set yrange [0:70000]
# set boxwidth 0.5 relative
# set label "Array list\n134908 ms" at graph 0.145,0.9

ArrayListColor   = "#491d75";
IndexedListColor = "#b32929";
LinkedListColor  = "#d49435";
TreeListColor    = "#12520b";

plot 'TotalDurationBarPlot.dat' using 1 title "Indexed list" linecolor rgb IndexedListColor, '' using 2 title "Tree list" linecolor rgb TreeListColor, '' using 3 title "Array list" linecolor rgb ArrayListColor, '' using 4 title "Linked list" linecolor rgb LinkedListColor, '' u 0:1:1 with labels offset -6.0,-100.0 title ""

set terminal png size 650,350 enhanced font "Monospaced,13"
set output 'TotalDuration.png'
replot
exit
```

It produces:

[image: List comparison]

**Edit 1**

The `gnuplot` code provided in the answer by [@meuh](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/119298/meuh) produces the following plot:

[image: Bad bars]

Comment: You should move your post to stackoverflow.com where there are some very competent users who might answer you quickly.

Comment: @meuh Fair enough. Thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I followed some of the hints you got from stackoverflow and, in case you don't have your own solution yet, ended with this close-enough approximation, using the original multiline data file.

```
set terminal png size 650,350 enhanced font "Monospaced,13"
set output 'TotalDuration.png'
set style fill solid border 2
set key noautotitle
set key box opaque fillcolor "0x7faaaaaa"
set grid x,y
set boxwidth 0.8 relative
set ylabel "Milliseconds"
set yrange [0:90000]

Array   = 0x491d75
Indexed = 0xb32929
Linked  = 0xd49435
Tree    = 0x12520b

list=""
plot 'TotalDurationBarPlot.dat' \
    u 0:3:(value(strcol(1))):xtic(1)   with boxes lc rgb var, \
 '' u 0:3:3:(list=list." ".stringcolumn(1)) with labels offset 0,0.7, \
 for [i=1:4] '' u (NaN):(NaN):(value(word(list,i))) with boxes lc rgb var title word(list,i)
```

I had to resort to gnuplot 6.1, in order to get the key "fillcolor" option,
but that should also be in 5.4, which I don't have to hand. The main feature used here is to save the column 1 text ("Indexed", "Tree",...) in a string variable `list`, and then use `word(list,i)` to extract one word for the title. The for loop reads the file but does not plot anything as all the data is invalid, `NaN`.

The colours are set in 4 variables that have the same name as column 1 of
the data. You get column 1 as a string with `strcol(1)`, then use function
`value()` to get the value of a variable of that name. This is an integer
which is used by `lc rgb var`. The same is done in the `for` loop, but here
the name is obtained from the collected `list` of names.

[image: plot]

I suggest that for any single aspect of this output that you want to change, you post a question on stackoverflow, so that iteratively you get to the answer you want.

Comment: Thank you for your time! Just one more detail: how could I control the bar colors in the gnuplot script you have provided? In my script, they are defined with `ArrayListColor`, `IndexedListColor`, etc.

Comment: I've updated with a possible solution. You can see the diffs if you click on the link "edited XX hours/days ago".

Comment: Cant quite replicate the plot in your answer.

Comment: That's a little vague. Are you using gnuplot 6.1?

Comment: I use version 5.4.6.

Comment: How did you install gnuplot 6.1? It’s not listed on sourceforge. Did you compile from source?

Comment: Yes I compiled ok from `git clone --depth 1 https://git.code.sf.net/p/gnuplot/gnuplot-main`. `cd gnuplot*;./prepare; ./configure;make;`. On fedora I needed package `gd-devel`. Instead of `make install` which needs root to install in /usr/local etc, I used `make install DESTDIR=$PWD/x` to get all in a subdir `x`. To run then need `export GNUPLOT_DRIVER_DIR=$PWD/x/usr/local/libexec/gnuplot/$vers/;` `export GNUPLOT_PS_DIR=$PWD/x/usr/local/share/gnuplot/$vers/PostScript/;`
`$PWD/x/usr/local/bin/gnuplot ... usual args`,  where `vers=$(awk <Makefile '/VERSION_MAJOR/{print $NF}')`, i.e. 6.1.

Comment: I just tried version 5.4.7 and it seems ok, so your version 5.4.6 was almost there.

Comment: 5.4.7 on Windows does not produce your result PNG.

Comment: Strange. I have installed gnuplot 6.1, yet it does not seem to support png terminal to begin with.

Comment: Wait, I think I need gd-devel first.

Comment: Indeed, I had to install `gd-devel` first before `gnuplot`.

Comment: I edited my question (see **Edit 1**). It contains my results with the script you kindly provided.

Comment: You mentioned Windows earlier. I've never used Windows, nor even Linux for Windows, so I am unlikely to be any help. Perhaps there is a problem with line endings, as my data file has just a newline between lines, whereas Windows might have crlf ? Perhaps you have to tell gnuplot that? It looks a bit like you are missing every 2nd line of data. Perhaps you should start a new question with more details of your environment and asking why it doesnt work.